# How to send bulk mailing to several dozen of thousand of recepients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, bulk

I have a task. Namely, I need to send a bulk mailing to several dozen of recepients during a working day (in several hours).

Could you clarify me, how can I do it using method SendBulkTemplatedEmail ?
As I understood, this method can send e-mails to no more than 50 recipients.

Can I split my array of recipients to parts by 50 recepients in each part and call this method for each portion separately ? Will it work ?

Comment: You can architect you application as follows: Have a producer and consumer service with kafka in between. Ensure you have idempotency built on producer (you can use the redlock algorithm for this) to prevent duplicates on reruns. On the producer, read from the database via a cursor with batchsize 50 and send it to kafka topic. Consumer will consume this from the topic and send the request to AWS SES API after some validations or payload massaging